# Warning: Google geocoding failed

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Getting error on my website please help me with the issue,

> Warning: Google geocoding failed. (Status: REQUEST_DENIED, Address:
>   Bella Vista, Golfito PUNTARENAS PROVINCE Costa Rica) in
>   /home/v6jl0h0nxthi/askzipy.com/includes/class_map.php on line 431
>
> Fatal Error (Uncaught Exception): Call to undefined method
>   Google_Map::getMapURLCoordinates() in
>   /home/v6jl0h0nxthi/askzipy.com/event.php on line 147

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Geocoding API - REQUEST\_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212550/google-geocoding-api-request-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Google is becoming more restrictive about their APIs. Try one of the many alternatives: eg: https://geocode.xyz/Bella%20Vista,%20Golfito%20PUNTARENAS%20PROVINCE%20Costa%20Rica

Costa Rica x,y z: 8.63967,-83.16513

1 Bella Vista, Golfito, Costa Rica Confidence Score: 0.5

Comment: Hi ervin thanks for comment but i am using phpmydirectory as a backend and not sure how i can solve this from this backend